# Loop over two XML lists

Tags: java, xml, groovy

I have a response like below, that contains two lists. The first list is *FILE_SET* the second list is *FILE_LIST*. I would like to loop and return the second list 
the *FILE_LIST*. I tried to do that with the code below, but it returns only the first list *FILE_SET*. How can I in groovy or java loop and return the second list?

XML response

```
<FILE_SET_LIST>
    <FILE_SET>
        <FILE_LIST>
            <FILE>
                <DATETIME>2013-06-07T00:00:00+02:00</DATETIME>
                <FILE_ID>W123</FILE_ID>
                <FILE_TYPE>Doc</FILE_TYPE>
                </FILE>
            <FILE>
                <DATETIME>2013-06-07T00:00:00+02:00</DATETIME>
                <FILE_ID>W125</FILE_ID>
                <FILE_TYPE>Letter</FILE_TYPE>
            </FILE>
        </FILE_LIST>
    </FILE_SET>
</FILE_SET_LIST>
```

My code

```
response.FILESETLIST?.FILESETS?.collect() {

            it.FILELIST?.FILES?.collect() {
                FILE file = new FILE()

                file.FileId = it.FILEID
                file.Date = it.CREATIONDATETIME
                file.FileType = it.FILETYPE

                file
            }
        }
```

Comment: Here is an example: http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5736754531270656

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is missing the underlines in the nodes' names and there is no `FILE` class. You can collect a map from each `FILE` element:

```
xml = '''<FILE_SET_LIST>
  <FILE_SET>
      <FILE_LIST>
          <FILE>
              <DATETIME>2013-06-07T00:00:00+02:00</DATETIME>
              <FILE_ID>W123</FILE_ID>
              <FILE_TYPE>Doc</FILE_TYPE>
             </FILE>
          <FILE>
              <DATETIME>2013-06-07T00:00:00+02:00</DATETIME>
              <FILE_ID>W125</FILE_ID>
              <FILE_TYPE>Letter</FILE_TYPE>
            </FILE>
      </FILE_LIST>
  </FILE_SET>
</FILE_SET_LIST>'''

response = new XmlSlurper().parseText xml

files = response.FILE_SET.FILE_LIST.FILE.collect { file ->
  return [
    fileType: file.FILE_TYPE,
    fileId: file.FILE_ID,
    dateTime: file.DATETIME
  ]
}

assert files.size() == 2
assert files[0].fileType == 'Doc'
assert files[1].fileId == 'W125'
```

Comment: @mesut, if this answer solves your problem you should accept it as the correct answer